# Why is the app still active in background on ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

Ok, so my will acctualy need a background location updates from time to time, but certanly not allways. So to do that I enabled Backgroud Mode for location updates  and create location manager in singleton and then when user needs the location it begins the updated and if dont it stop manager from updating.

Later I figure it out that if the location is updating the app is still active in background. But strange is that the same happens even if the updates are disabled.

I even removed the code that creates the CLLocationManager, so its 'nil' the whole time, but when I go out of the app, the app is still running in background. How is this possible. I also tried with stopping location updates on manager. I really need that app is acting like normal apps when there is no need for location updates, for the sake of battery usage.

I there a way to prevent app from running in background when there is no need for locaiton.

Comment: How are you testing that it's running and is it connected to Xcode at the time?

Comment: I test it connected to xcode. I also have a one function of CMMotionManager that checks the accelerations of the phone, and its executing even if it's in background.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode keeps the app awake, disconnect to properly test background operation. If you have specified the background mode in your plist for entitlements then the specified services will be allowed to run and update in certain circumstances (different for each service).

You should turn all active services off when your app is notified it goes to the background and test away from Xcode.

Comment: Ok. I'll try. So if I understand you right, I should log location updates in the app documents file, and disconnect the phone from xcode and see if it's logging in the background?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: And you don't have background modes enabled, you only request permission for 'while active' and you stop updates when going to the background?

Comment: bacground mode is enabled, because sometimes the location needs to be updated in background.

Comment: I created a dummy xcode project (with location bacground mode ON) and there I stopped updating location manager and put app in background. And in this case the app stop running. Which is right way. Where should be a problem that in my real app it keeps running. I think something else must keep the app awake. Is it possible that it's something wrong with parse? I user parse.com service to use it as a server for the app.

Comment: If you didn't request parse code to do anything then it should be fine

Comment: No, as far as I know it shouldnt do anything at that time. It's also hard to bo possible that this is parse fault because if I disable location background mode, the app is not running in background.

Comment: parse does have some location capability IIRC, but you need to request it

Comment: Yeah I does, but I dont use it. I'll take a look at my code carefully and try to find a bug. As I saw in a dummy project it should work easly. Till now I was worried that maybe its ios bug. Thanks for help.

Comment: Oh I find the problem. My coworker add another cllocationmanager in one of the classes to access a region around the user to search for a places nearby. Now everything works great. Thank you again.